# AWS ElasticLoadBalancer certificate doesn't match domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, certificate, amazon-elb

I'm a bit confused as to how Elastic Load Balancers work with certificates in AWS.  The domain name for my ELB is my-service1234568698.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com and that's what I used to call my REST endpoints (I have my ELB palming requests off to docker instances with Java microservices).

I have my own domain and I have created an Amazon certificate for it in ACM but that's for www.my-domain-here.com, not the amazon ELB one.  When I try and call the ELB over https I get a CORS error because the certificate name doesn't match the AWS domain name.  Calling it with CURL and specifying the origin host, I get:

curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'my-service1234568698.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com'

Any idea on how this is supposed to work?

Comment: posted an answer for you, you did everything correct, but you missed one step which is pointing your domain to your load balancer's dns name. once you do it, you can call the url via your domain. good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you are missing is , you should point `www.my-domain.com` to `my-service1234568698.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` in your domain management system(Rotue53 if you are using aws). then you should curl using your domain `curl www.my-domain.com`

If you are using Route53,
create an `A` record for `www.my-domain.com` pointing to `my-service1234568698.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` and set `Alias` to `Yes`

Answer (score 2):

Certificate needs to be attached to your SSL termination endpoint in your AWS environment. Load balancer are generally used as the SSL termination endpoint, which means they will do all the SSL handshake and secure connection setup. To do that your Load balancer needs to know the cert, chain and the private key. You can do all that using AWS console.

Registering a domain name and creating a certificate do not secure your domain. As you still need to apply the certificate to your domain origin or a public endpoint in your AWS environment. Not sure where have you applied that? If certificate is only requested through ACM and not attached anywhere then your load balancer can be a valid choice depending on your whole setup.

**EDIT:**  As per the comments, also you need to create a CNAME record in route 53 to point your own domain to your load balancer. So that you don't need hit the cryptic load balancer domaoin name, instead you cna use your own registered domain.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I am using the certificate on my load balancer endpoint but my question was more about the fact that when I registered the certificate in ACM, I put in the domain name of www.my-domain.com. When I make an https REST call to my AWS load balancer, the url (or domain name) is the AWS-specified one (that ends in amazonaws.com) and that domain name doesn’t match the one registered on the certificate.

Comment: Because you need to create a CNAME record in route 53 to point your own domain to your load balancer. So that you don't need hit the cryptic load balancer domaoin name, instead you cna use your own registered domain.

Answer (score 0):

I see, I get it now. So www.my-domain.com is hosted by another provider (I.e. not on aws) and it’s where my SPA is hosted (using REACT). My idea was that I’d make calls to my AWS back end from there. If I want to use https on an elastic load balancer, does that mean I need two domains then? One for my website and one so I can use a certificate within aws?

Comment: You can either do it with two domains(mydomain.com, mydomain2.com), or with two subdomains of the same domain (website,mydomain.com, api.webdomain.com). You dont need a separate domain just to get a ssl certificate. You can get a certificate for any existing domain or subdomain. Hope this helps

Comment: I see. Thanks again for your post. Do you know if it’s possible to create an SSL certificate on Amazon Certificate manager which points to ‘my’ my-service.1234567.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com domain? Couldn’t see a way of adding it

Comment: certificates does not point anywhere. you can create a certificate for any domain you own. once you have a certificate issued for lets say `*.mydomain.com` then you can assign it to a load balancer. you can point your domain to ‘my’ my-service.1234567.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` regardess of whether you have a certificate or not

Comment: Actually, I've just seen that you can't: 

Note

You cannot request a certificate for Amazon-owned domain names such as those ending in amazonaws.com, cloudfront.net, or elasticbeanstalk.com.

Comment: i got your question wrong, you can only get the certificate for the domain you own. yes.

Comment: After lots of research and trial and error, I've come to the conclusion that it's not possible to add a subdomain (using Namecheap at least) to my main domain (www.my-domain.com) and repoint that sub domain to my ...elb.amazonaws.com Elastic Load Balancer.  I can't believe how tricky this stuff is to work with.  I think I'm going to have to buy yet another domain so I can setup proper DNS re-routing on that rather than a simple redirect (that seems to be the only thing I can do on a subdomain with NameCheap)

Comment: let me know if you need help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204174/discussion-between-user1387735-and-arun-k).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys (and, Arun, appreciate the chat), got this sorted and working now.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue, may I ask what is the resolution?